# Compiling Qt project in a directory outside of the install directory

Tags: qt, qt4, qmake

I've been working on a project using OpenCV for a while, and am ready to upgrade my user interface from using `cvWaitKey()` to get key presses and emulating buttons with trackbars. Ha. So I've decided to use Qt.

I'd like to continue developing in the same directory I've been using, which is, of course, outside of the Qt install directory, C:\Qt\2010.05\qt. Using the "Qt Command Prompt", I'm able to compile the Hello Notepad example in directories both in and out of C:\Qt\2010.05\qt, namely C:\Qt\2010.05\qt\abc and C:\Qt\2010.05\abc.

However, while compiling under C:\ ... \qt produces executables in both the debug and release directories, compiling outside of it only produces the debug executable, along with a .o file (object code?). I did some comparisons using WinMerge, and found that the following lines (among others) differ in the two makefiles (generated using `qmake -project` and then `qmake`):

Inside qt\

```
first: all  
install: debug-install release-install  
uninstall: debug-uninstall release-uninstall
```

Outside qt\

```
first: debug  
install: debug-install  
uninstall: debug-uninstall
```

That's clearly the problem (the .pro files generated by `qmake -project` differ only in timestamp). I'm sure there's an easy answer out there to what's causing this... I *hope* there's an easy answer to how I can work around it. Also, I intend to use QtCreator some; hopefully the solution is the same for the IDE as the Command-Line compiler.

Thanks!

Nolan

p.s.: I don't think this is the same issue: [Qmake does not support build directories below the source directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4061184/qt-qmake-does-not-support-build-directories-below-the-source-directory) ...in any case, I'm not sure I understand the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add

```
CONFIG += release
```

to your .pro file, to build for release target.  There's also

```
CONFIG += debug_and_release
```

iirc.

QtCreator has a GUI element for toggling between build targets, you might try opening the .pro with that application if you find you need to switch back and forth often.

Comment: quite so, now we have completeness :)

Comment: But why the change when I move outside the directory? And so far, I haven't been able to find the option or combination of options that will build both debug and release (i.e., `debug_and_release` didn't do it; neither did `CONFIG += debug`, `CONFIG += release`). I am able to build one at a time and control which using CONFIG, though.

Comment: After looking through the qmake manual's entry for the `CONFIG` variable: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qmake-variable-reference.html#config , I see that if I specify `debug_and_release` and then either use `make all` or specify `CONFIG += build_all`, I can get both the release and debug versions built.

Strangely, though, the way the .o files are saved varies a bit depending on where the directory is. Also, I'm still left wondering why qmake cares where its directory is.